# A program that determines the nth positive root of the p

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to count the *nth* positive root of p for example we have **n=2** and **p=16** the answer is **4** because
**4^2 = 16**. I want to do this for huge numbers (**1 <= n <= 200**, **1 <= p < 10^101**). I don't know how should I do it as fast as possible.

### Example:

```
n=2 p=16      Answer 4  
n=7 p=4357186184021382204544    Answer 1234
```

Comment: Well, what did you try so far? What was the issue, was it to slow? Show us some work

Comment: So here is the problem I don't know how to calculate this huge numbers in c++ because obviously they are bigger than anything I just have one way to get numbers with array but still I don't know how to calculate!!!!!

Comment: You should probably say "principal root", since the roots can be complex, not just negative.

Comment: Well then you may be in much bigger need than a simple stack overflow question. I would start by looking up how you can calculate the root of a number by hand. Then convert that into a program. Then work on performance of it.

Comment: I said that always 1 <= n <= 200,1 <= p < 10^101 and 1 <= k <= 10^9

Comment: What's wrong with pow(p,1.0/n)?

Comment: The problem is that p is so big,bigger than `unsigned long long int`

Comment: What is k in your above comment "I said... 1<=k<=10^9"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are arbitrary precision math packages out there, if you have to come up with your own algorithm.
But you might try this:  Get p into a double any way you can (a double can handle 10^101.)  Then use math.h::pow(p, 1.0/n), and that answer will be close to the right integer (round it?).   But this will fail if p is more than 15 digits, and n is too small, e.g., p = 10^100, n=2 gives a 50 digit answer, which is too big an integer for double to represent exactly.

Get 101 digit p into double: cut the number (string) into 10 digit chunks, multiply each by 10 to the appropriate power, and add them up.

Answer (score 0):

Try Newton's method as described here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Take log of p, divide by n, and take the anti-log:

```
nthRoot(p, n) := Math.Power(10, Math.Log(p) / n)
```

Not sure whether you're specifically dealing with integers or what but that is the psuedo-code for it.

Comment: Just there is one more problem that p is so big,bigger than `unsigned long long int`

Comment: You have to explain what form that p is taking.  Is it a BigInteger in C#?  Is it a string?  What language are you using?  The answer depends on all this.  If it's a BigInteger in most languages then there's almost assuredly a BigInteger version of Log so just use it.  If it's a string and you want to avoid BigIntegers, then use base 10 logs and strip off enough lower precision digits until you end up with something you can put into a float/double in whatever language you're using, increasing the log by 1 for every digit stripped.